# MbUnit: How to notify a routine under test that it was called from the testing environment

Tags: unit-testing, mbunit

I have a routine that reads directory information from the registry. If called from the test environment it needs to return one location (a test data directory). If not called from the test environment it needs to return another location (where production data lives).
Can someone give me a clue on how to accomplish this?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me that you need to use [Dependency Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection).  I also would recommend to use [Inversion of Control (IoC)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversion_of_control) container.  There are a lot of information on the web about DI and IoC.

Comment: I was really hoping for something within the world of MbUnit simply noting that testing is happening.

Comment: Despite that MbUnit has more features than any other Unit Testing framework (in my opinion) and you're paying the price either you're using these features or not, there's nothing MbUnit can do to solve your problem.  Dependency Inject is the way you want to go.